# Bitwise operator ~ goes wrong

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I'm learning the bitwise operators in C. When I calculate the outcome of ~4 I get 11, also when I calculate it on a website I get the same outcome. But my compiler gives me the wrong result, everytime when I compile I get 5. I think my compiler settings are wrong. I searched on the internet for the problem but didn't find anything.

What can I do to solve this?

```
int x = ~4;
    printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: How do you calculate your outcome?

Comment: With pen and paper. I first write down the binary representation of 4, then I switch the 1's to 0's and vice versa. I checked on the internet if I'm doing something wrong but I don't I believe.

Comment: How many `1` do you get when you do that?

Comment: 4 = 0100   ~4 = 1011 @Gerhardh

Comment: You know, that an `int` has more than 4 bits, do you? Also I doubt that you get `5` from your compiler. I would expect `-5`.

Comment: Yes -5, but that's still wrong

Answer (score 4):

You have not taken into account that data types have a certain size which is fixed independently from its content.

On most modern systems, an `int` has 32 bits. This means your `4` is represented as

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100`

and when you do `~` you get

`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011`.

As `int` is a signed data type and (on most modern systems) two's complement is used for representing negative values, this is shown as `-5`.

Comment: I think the guy from the tutorial I watched explains it wrong. Now I understand thnx!

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you watched. Maybe you need to look again and keep an eye on the tiny details. If they were doing it with unsigned values and used limited number of bits just to demonstrate how the operator works, then it would be correct. You just cannot use it in your code without knowing the context.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer should be -5.

```
 4 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
~4 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011
```

This is the binary representation of -5 using a 32-bit signed integer. For signed integers, `~x=-x-1`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the easiest way to show you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main() {
    printf("%o\n", 4);
    printf("%o %d\n", ~4, ~4);
    printf("%o %d\n", 4 + ~4, 4 + ~4);
    return 0;
}
```

will display:

```
4
37777777773 -5
37777777777 -1
```

If you add 4 to the last octet 3 of the octal encoding you get 7 hence complement was applied as as expected.  Why is the 2nd number looking so strange, that's because it's encoded as twos compliment.